# How to use Filesink in Deepstream test application to save video

Tags: nvidia-deepstream

Hello everyone my question is related with Nvidia Deepstream-5.0 SDK,

I am trying to run a sample test **deepstream-nvdsanalytics-test** which is in "/source/apps/sample_apps" in NVIDIA Deepstream container. I want to save the video file by using **Filesink**. I got the suggestion to look into **create_encode_file_bin** function which is in"/source/apps/apps-common/src/deepstream_sink_bin.c".

I tried changing the code **deepstream_nvdsanalytics_test.cpp** taking create_encode_file_bin as a reference but got some errors. I am posting my pipeline, edited code and error please have a look.

pipeline used-

> pgie->nvtracker->nvdsanalytics->tiler->nvvidconv->nvosd->nvideoconvvert->caps
>   filter(x/raw)->encoder->codecparse->mux->filesink

Error-

> (deepstream-nvdsanalytics-test:203): GStreamer-WARNING **:
>   16:08:13.115: Name ‘nvvideo-converter’ is not unique in bin
>   ‘nvdsanalytics-test-pipeline’, not adding
>
> (deepstream-nvdsanalytics-test:203): GStreamer-CRITICAL **:
>   16:08:13.116: gst_element_link_pads_full: assertion ‘GST_IS_ELEMENT
>   (dest)’ failed Elements could not be linked. Exiting.

code-

> ```
> #include <gst/gst.h>
> #include <glib.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <math.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #include <sys/time.h>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <unordered_map>
> #include "gstnvdsmeta.h"
> #include "nvds_analytics_meta.h"
> #include "deepstream_config.h"
> #ifndef PLATFORM_TEGRA
> #include "gst-nvmessage.h"
> #endif
>
> [....]
>
> int
> main (int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>   GMainLoop *loop = NULL;
>   GstElement *pipeline = NULL, *streammux = NULL, *sink = NULL, *pgie = NULL,
>              *nvtracker = NULL, *nvdsanalytics = NULL,
>       *nvvidconv = NULL, *nvosd = NULL, *nvvidconv1 = NULL, *transform1 = NULL, *cap_filter = NULL, *encoder = NULL, *codecparse = NULL, *mux = NULL, *tiler = NULL;
>   GstCaps *caps = NULL;
>
> #ifdef PLATFORM_TEGRA
>   GstElement *transform = NULL;
> #endif
>   GstBus *bus = NULL;
>   guint bus_watch_id;
>   GstPad *nvdsanalytics_src_pad = NULL;
>   guint i, num_sources;
>   guint tiler_rows, tiler_columns;
>   guint pgie_batch_size;
>   gulong bitrate = 2000000;
>   guint profile = 0;
>
>   /* Check input arguments */
>   if (argc < 2) {
>     g_printerr ("Usage: %s <uri1> [uri2] ... [uriN] \n", argv[0]);
>     return -1;
>   }
>   num_sources = argc - 1;
>
>   /* Standard GStreamer initialization */
>   gst_init (&argc, &argv);
>   loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
>
>   /* Create gstreamer elements */
>   /* Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements */
>   pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("nvdsanalytics-test-pipeline");
>
>   /* Create nvstreammux instance to form batches from one or more sources. */
>   streammux = gst_element_factory_make ("nvstreammux", "stream-muxer");
>
>   if (!pipeline || !streammux) {
>     g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>     return -1;
>   }
>   gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (pipeline), streammux);
>
>   for (i = 0; i < num_sources; i++) {
>     GstPad *sinkpad, *srcpad;
>     gchar pad_name[16] = { };
>     GstElement *source_bin = create_source_bin (i, argv[i + 1]);
>
>     if (!source_bin) {
>       g_printerr ("Failed to create source bin. Exiting.\n");
>       return -1;
>     }
>
>     gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (pipeline), source_bin);
>
>     g_snprintf (pad_name, 15, "sink_%u", i);
>     sinkpad = gst_element_get_request_pad (streammux, pad_name);
>     if (!sinkpad) {
>       g_printerr ("Streammux request sink pad failed. Exiting.\n");
>       return -1;
>     }
>
>     srcpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (source_bin, "src");
>     if (!srcpad) {
>       g_printerr ("Failed to get src pad of source bin. Exiting.\n");
>       return -1;
>     }
>
>     if (gst_pad_link (srcpad, sinkpad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {
>       g_printerr ("Failed to link source bin to stream muxer. Exiting.\n");
>       return -1;
>     }
>
>     gst_object_unref (srcpad);
>     gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
>   }
>
>   /* Use nvinfer to infer on batched frame. */
>   pgie = gst_element_factory_make ("nvinfer", "primary-nvinference-engine");
>
>   /* Use nvtracker to track detections on batched frame. */
>   nvtracker = gst_element_factory_make ("nvtracker", "nvtracker");
>
>   /* Use nvdsanalytics to perform analytics on object */
>   nvdsanalytics = gst_element_factory_make ("nvdsanalytics", "nvdsanalytics");
>
>   /* Use nvtiler to composite the batched frames into a 2D tiled array based
>    * on the source of the frames. */
>   tiler = gst_element_factory_make ("nvmultistreamtiler", "nvtiler");
>
>   /* Use convertor to convert from NV12 to RGBA as required by nvosd */
>   nvvidconv = gst_element_factory_make ("nvvideoconvert", "nvvideo-converter");
>   if (!nvvidconv) {
>     g_printerr ("nvvdiconv element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>
>   /* Create OSD to draw on the converted RGBA buffer */
>   nvosd = gst_element_factory_make ("nvdsosd", "nv-onscreendisplay");
>   if (!nvosd) {
>     g_printerr ("nvosd element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>
>   /* converter to convert RGBA to NV12 */
>   nvvidconv1 = gst_element_factory_make ("nvvideoconvert", "nvvideo-converter1");
>   if (!nvvidconv1) {
>     g_printerr ("nvvidconv1 element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>   /*create cap_filter */
>   cap_filter = gst_element_factory_make (NVDS_ELEM_CAPS_FILTER, "cap_filter");
>   if (!cap_filter) {
>     g_printerr ("cap_filter element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>
>   /* create cap for filter */
>   caps = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw, format=I420");
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (cap_filter), "caps", caps, NULL);
>
>   /* creatge encoder*/
>   encoder = gst_element_factory_make (NVDS_ELEM_ENC_H264_HW, "encoder");
>   if (!encoder) {
>     g_printerr ("encoder element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>
>   /* create transform1 */
>   transform1 = gst_element_factory_make (NVDS_ELEM_VIDEO_CONV, "transform1");
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (transform1), "gpu-id", 0, NULL);
>   if (!transform1) {
>     g_printerr ("transform1 element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>
>   #ifdef IS_TEGRA
>     g_object_set (G_OBJECT (encoder), "bufapi-version", 1, NULL);
>   #endif
>
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (encoder), "profile", profile, NULL);
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (encoder), "bitrate", bitrate, NULL);
>
>   /* create codecparse */
>   codecparse = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "h264-parser");
>   if (!codecparse) {
>     g_printerr ("codecparse element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>   /* create mux */
>   mux = gst_element_factory_make (NVDS_ELEM_MUX_MP4, "mux");
>   if (!mux) {
>     g_printerr ("mux element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>
>   /* create sink */
>   sink = gst_element_factory_make (NVDS_ELEM_SINK_FILE, "filesink");
>   if (!sink) {
>     g_printerr ("sink element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>   }
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "location", "capture.mp4", "sync", 0, "async" , FALSE, NULL);
>
> //   /* Finally render the osd output */
> #ifdef PLATFORM_TEGRA
>   transform = gst_element_factory_make ("nvegltransform", "nvegl-transform");
> #endif
> //   sink = gst_element_factory_make (NVDS_ELEM_SINK_FILE, "filesink");
> //   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "location", "capture.mp4", "sync", 0, "async" , FALSE, NULL);
>
>   if (!pgie || !nvtracker || !nvdsanalytics || !nvvidconv ||
>       !nvosd || !nvvidconv1 || !cap_filter || !encoder || !codecparse || !mux || !sink) {
>     g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>     return -1;
>   }
>
> #ifdef PLATFORM_TEGRA
>   if(!transform) {
>     g_printerr ("One tegra element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
>     return -1;
>   }
> #endif
>
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (streammux), "width", MUXER_OUTPUT_WIDTH, "height",
>       MUXER_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, "batch-size", num_sources,
>       "batched-push-timeout", MUXER_BATCH_TIMEOUT_USEC, NULL);
>
>   /* Configure the nvinfer element using the nvinfer config file. */
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pgie),
>       "config-file-path", "nvdsanalytics_pgie_config.txt", NULL);
>
>   /* Configure the nvtracker element for using the particular tracker algorithm. */
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (nvtracker),
>       "ll-lib-file", "/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/lib/libnvds_nvdcf.so",
>       "ll-config-file", "tracker_config.yml", "tracker-width", 640, "tracker-height", 480,
>        NULL);
>
>   /* Configure the nvdsanalytics element for using the particular analytics config file*/
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (nvdsanalytics),
>       "config-file", "config_nvdsanalytics.txt",
>        NULL);
>
>   /* Override the batch-size set in the config file with the number of sources. */
>   g_object_get (G_OBJECT (pgie), "batch-size", &pgie_batch_size, NULL);
>   if (pgie_batch_size != num_sources) {
>     g_printerr
>         ("WARNING: Overriding infer-config batch-size (%d) with number of sources (%d)\n",
>         pgie_batch_size, num_sources);
>     g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pgie), "batch-size", num_sources, NULL);
>   }
>
>   tiler_rows = (guint) sqrt (num_sources);
>   tiler_columns = (guint) ceil (1.0 * num_sources / tiler_rows);
>   /* we set the tiler properties here */
>   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (tiler), "rows", tiler_rows, "columns", tiler_columns,
>       "width", TILED_OUTPUT_WIDTH, "height", TILED_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, NULL);
>
>   /* we add a message handler */
>   bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
>   bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
>   gst_object_unref (bus);
>
>   /* Set up the pipeline */
>   /* we add all elements into the pipeline */
> #ifdef PLATFORM_TEGRA
>   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), pgie, nvtracker, nvdsanalytics ,
>           nvvidconv, nvosd, nvvidconv1, cap_filter, encoder, codecparse, mux, sink,
>       NULL);
>
>   /* we link the elements together
>    * nvstreammux -> nvinfer -> nvtracker -> nvdsanalytics -> nvtiler ->
>    * nvvideoconvert -> nvosd -> transform -> sink
>    */
>   if (!gst_element_link_many (streammux, pgie, nvtracker, nvdsanalytics,
>                               nvvidconv, nvosd, nvvidconv1, cap_filter, encoder, codecparse, mux, sink, NULL)) {
>     g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked. Exiting.\n");
>     return -1;
>   }
> #else
>   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), pgie, nvtracker, nvdsanalytics,
>                     nvvidconv, nvosd, nvvidconv1, cap_filter, encoder, codecparse, mux, sink, NULL);
>   /* we link the elements together
>    * nvstreammux -> nvinfer -> nvtracker -> nvdsanalytics -> nvtiler ->
>    * nvvideoconvert -> nvosd -> sink
>    */
>   if (!gst_element_link_many (streammux, pgie, nvtracker, nvdsanalytics,
>       nvvidconv, nvosd, nvvidconv1, cap_filter, encoder, codecparse, mux, sink, NULL)) {
>     g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked. Exiting.\n");
>     return -1;
>   }
> #endif
>
>   /* Lets add probe to get informed of the meta data generated, we add probe to
>    * the sink pad of the nvdsanalytics element, since by that time, the buffer
>    * would have had got all the metadata.
>    */
>   nvdsanalytics_src_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (nvdsanalytics, "src");
>   if (!nvdsanalytics_src_pad)
>     g_print ("Unable to get src pad\n");
>   else
>     gst_pad_add_probe (nvdsanalytics_src_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
>         nvdsanalytics_src_pad_buffer_probe, NULL, NULL);
>
>   /* Set the pipeline to "playing" state */
>   g_print ("Now playing:");
>   for (i = 0; i < num_sources; i++) {
>     g_print (" %s,", argv[i + 1]);
>   }
>   g_print ("\n");
>   gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
>
>   /* Wait till pipeline encounters an error or EOS */
>   g_print ("Running...\n");
>   g_main_loop_run (loop);
>
>   /* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */
>   g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
>   gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
>   g_print ("Deleting pipeline\n");
>   gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
>   g_source_remove (bus_watch_id);
>   g_main_loop_unref (loop);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Please let me know if any other information is required from my side. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the pipeline as per the below git diff (note: the below diff is for `deepstream-test2` app, it'll work `deepstream-nvdsanalytics-test` as well) [source](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/encoding-and-saving-to-a-file-with-deepstream-test1-app-c/63362/2?u=kharshit.kr):

```cpp
diff --git a/deepstream-test2/deepstream_test2_app.c b/deepstream-test2/deepstream_test2_app.c
index 2b1ff34..c31441e 100644
--- a/deepstream-test2/deepstream_test2_app.c
+++ b/deepstream-test2/deepstream_test2_app.c
@@ -318,6 +318,16 @@ main (int argc, char *argv[])
   GstBus *bus = NULL;
   guint bus_watch_id = 0;
   GstPad *osd_sink_pad = NULL;
+  
+  /* Added to save output to file */
+  GstElement *nvvidconv1 = NULL,
+      *filter1 = NULL, *filter2 = NULL,
+      *filter3 = NULL,
+      *videoconvert = NULL,
+      *filter4 = NULL,
+      *x264enc = NULL,
+      *qtmux = NULL;
+  GstCaps *caps1 = NULL, *caps2 = NULL, *caps3 = NULL, *caps4 = NULL;
 
   /* Check input arguments */
   if (argc != 2) {
@@ -373,17 +383,35 @@ main (int argc, char *argv[])
   /* Create OSD to draw on the converted RGBA buffer */
   nvosd = gst_element_factory_make ("nvdsosd", "nv-onscreendisplay");
 
+  /* Added to save output to file */
+  nvvidconv1 = gst_element_factory_make ("nvvideoconvert", "nvvideo-converter1");
+  videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "converter");
+  x264enc = gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", "h264 encoder");
+  qtmux = gst_element_factory_make ("qtmux", "muxer");
+
   /* Finally render the osd output */
 #ifdef PLATFORM_TEGRA
   transform = gst_element_factory_make ("nvegltransform", "nvegl-transform");
 #endif
-  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("nveglglessink", "nvvideo-renderer");
+  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", "nvvideo-renderer");
+
+  /* caps filter for nvvidconv to convert NV12 to RGBA as nvosd expects input
+    * in RGBA format */
+  filter1 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "filter1");
+  filter2 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "filter2");
+  filter3 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "filter3");
+  filter4 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "filter4");
 
   if (!source || !h264parser || !decoder || !pgie ||
       !nvtracker || !sgie1 || !sgie2 || !sgie3 || !nvvidconv || !nvosd || !sink) {
     g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
     return -1;
   }
+  /* Added to test saving output to file */
+  if (!nvvidconv1 || !x264enc || !qtmux || !filter3 || !filter4) {
+    g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
+    return -1;
+  }
 
 #ifdef PLATFORM_TEGRA
   if(!transform) {
@@ -395,6 +423,9 @@ main (int argc, char *argv[])
   /* Set the input filename to the source element */
   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", argv[1], NULL);
 
+  /* Added to save output to file */
+  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "location", "out.mp4", NULL);
+
   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (streammux), "batch-size", 1, NULL);
 
   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (streammux), "width", MUXER_OUTPUT_WIDTH, "height",
@@ -429,9 +460,24 @@ main (int argc, char *argv[])
 #else
   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),
       source, h264parser, decoder, streammux, pgie, nvtracker, sgie1, sgie2, sgie3,
-      nvvidconv, nvosd, sink, NULL);
+      filter1, nvvidconv, filter2, nvosd, nvvidconv1, filter3, videoconvert, filter4,
+      x264enc, qtmux, sink, NULL);
 #endif
 
+  /* Added to save output to file */
+  caps1 = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=NV12");
+  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter1), "caps", caps1, NULL);
+  gst_caps_unref (caps1);
+  caps2 = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=RGBA");
+  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter2), "caps", caps2, NULL);
+  gst_caps_unref (caps2);
+  caps3 = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw, format=RGBA");
+  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter3), "caps", caps3, NULL);
+  gst_caps_unref (caps3);
+  caps4 = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw, format=NV12");
+  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter4), "caps", caps4, NULL);
+  gst_caps_unref (caps4);
+
   GstPad *sinkpad, *srcpad;
   gchar pad_name_sink[16] = "sink_0";
   gchar pad_name_src[16] = "src";
@@ -470,7 +516,8 @@ main (int argc, char *argv[])
   }
 #else
   if (!gst_element_link_many (streammux, pgie, nvtracker, sgie1,
-      sgie2, sgie3, nvvidconv, nvosd, sink, NULL)) {
+      sgie2, sgie3, filter1, nvvidconv, filter2, nvosd, nvvidconv1, filter3,
+      videoconvert, filter4, x264enc, qtmux, sink, NULL)) {
     g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked. Exiting.\n");
     return -1;
   }
```

For `deepstream-nvdsanalytics-test`, pipeline would be:

```cpp
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), pgie, nvtracker, nvdsanalytics, tiler,
                    filter1, nvvidconv, filter2, nvosd, nvvidconv1, filter3, videoconvert, filter4,
                    x264enc, qtmux, sink, NULL);
```